# @RestControllerAdvice with MethodArgumentNotValidException handler does not work with testing

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing, mockmvc

My @RestControllerAdvice is not working when a MethodArgumentNotValidException exception is thrown running a controller unit test (even using **setControllerAdvice** method).

This is my unit test:

```
class MyControllerTestSlice {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private ResultActions currentRequest;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MyController())
                         .alwaysDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                        .setControllerAdvice(new ControllerExceptionHandler())
                        .build();
    }

    @Test
    void test_post_with_handler_exception() throws Exception {
        JSONObject expectedResponse = new JSONObject().put("msg", "name required");
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/post", new Payload()))
            .andExpect(status().is(422))
            .andExpect(content().json(expectedResponse.toString()));
    }
}
```

This is my RestControllerAdvice:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String s = ex.getFieldErrors().stream().map(f -> f.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(new ErrorMessage(s));
    }

}
```

My body DTO:

```
public class Payload {
    public Payload() {}
    
    public Payload(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @NotNull(message = "name required")
    private String name;
    
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Test result (neither status nor body response are changed since RestControllerAdivce is not invoked):

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/post
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.demo.controller.MyController
           Method = com.example.demo.controller.MyController#post(Payload)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

However, same code with an integration test (using @SpringBootTest and TestRestTemplate) is working well.

What am I doing wrong?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

I was sending body in post request badly and it produces a HttpMessageNotReadableException instead of MethodArgumentNotValidException.

The correct way is:

```
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/post")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body)));
```

Now every works as I expected.

Thanks!.